# Two UITableView in single UIViewcontroller not working properly

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I want to implement following functionality in app show pict

[image]

But i have following problem show another pict

[image]

my code as follow

```
 // MARK:  UITextFieldDelegate Methods
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if str == "Loading"{
            return 0
        }else if tableView == tbl2{
            return arrSub.count
        }else{
                return self.displayData.count
        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell:customCellInvitation = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")as! customCellInvitation
        if tableView == tbl2{
//Code for the load secind table
            cell.lblUserName.text = self.arrSub.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("username") as?String
            cell.btnAdd.setImage(UIImage(named: "yes1.png"), forState:(UIControlState.Normal))
            return cell
        }else{
//Code for the load first table
            cell.lblUserName.text = self.displayData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("username") as?String
            cell.btnAdd.setImage(UIImage(named: "add.png"), forState:(UIControlState.Normal))
            cell.btnAdd.setImage(UIImage(named: "yes1.png"), forState:(UIControlState.Selected))
            cell.btnAdd.addTarget(self, action: "addData:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
            cell.btnAdd.tag  = indexPath.row
        }
        return cell
    }


    // MARK:  UITableViewDelegate Methods
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 44
    }
    //function call when user click Plus button
    func addData(sender: UIButton!) {
          arrSub .addObject(self.displayData .objectAtIndex(sender.tag))
        var button:UIButton = sender.viewWithTag(sender.tag) as! UIButton
        button.selected=true
        button.userInteractionEnabled = false
        NSLog("%@", arrSub)

        [tbl2 .reloadData()]
    }
```

Comment: What's the point of using two different tables in a single view? Aren't sections enough for doing what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    // MARK:  UITextFieldDelegate Methods

      func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            var cell:customCellInvitation = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")as! customCellInvitation
       if tableView == tbl2{
                cell.lblUserName.text = self.arrSub.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("username") as?String
          if str = "yes"{ 
                   cell.btnAdd.setImage(UIImage(named: "yes1.png"), forState:(UIControlState.Normal))

          }else{
                   cell.btnAdd.setImage(UIImage(named: "NO.png"), forState:(UIControlState.Normal))
          }
      return cell
       }else{
         cell.lblUserName.text = self.displayData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("username") as?String
             if str = "yes"{ 
               cell.btnAdd.setImage(UIImage(named: "yes1.png"), forState:(UIControlState.Normal))
      }else{
         cell.btnAdd.setImage(UIImage(named: "NO.png"), forState:(UIControlState.Normal))
      }
    }
    return cell
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to move your tableView Datasource and Delegate to separate classes. This is not a good practise at all. You will certainly mess up with your code.

Comment: Post you updated code after moving each tableView's datasource and delegate to a separate class.

Comment: That's great!! Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing make code complexity, you can add you own custom class for tableView and can maintain it it all delegate datasource methods.Add that tableview in current class and with giving frame to it. By this you can add as many number of tableview to a single class and no need to worry about data handling.

Answer (score 0):

Put a frame to this table view, then you can add two frame to a view controller. So add this frame to your view controller, you should adjust the frame width and hight in order to show two tables.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
    let tableView = UITableView()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.separatorStyle = .None
    tableView.frame = CGRectMake(20, (self.view.frame.size.height - 54 * 5) / 2.0, (self.view.frame.size.width - 25 * 5), 54 * 5)
    tableView.autoresizingMask = .FlexibleTopMargin | .FlexibleBottomMargin | .FlexibleWidth
    tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    tableView.opaque = false
    tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    tableView.backgroundView = nil
    tableView.bounces = false
    tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true

    return tableView
    }()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    view.addSubview(tableView)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}


// MARK : TableViewDataSource & Delegate Methods

extension LeftMenuViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 6
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 54
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    let titles: [String] = ["Home", "Features", "Pricing", "Help", "About Us", "Contact Us"] // put your titles

    let images: [String] = ["IconHome", "IconCalendar", "IconProfile", "IconSettings", "IconEmpty", "IconEmpty"] // add images if you want

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor() // optional 
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 21)
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    cell.textLabel?.text  = titles[indexPath.row]
    cell.selectionStyle = .None
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: images[indexPath.row])


    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBar") as! UIViewController

        sideMenuViewController?.contentViewController = viewController

        sideMenuViewController?.hideMenuViewController()
        break // show table navigation view controller 
    case 1:

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBar") as! UIViewController

        sideMenuViewController?.contentViewController = viewController

        sideMenuViewController?.hideMenuViewController()
        break // show table navigation view controller
    default:
        break
     }


  }

}
```